# Retrieve array with objects of similar property

Tags: arrays, swift3, filtering

I have my two objects (Obj1 & Obj2) defined as below:

```
class Obj1: NSObject {
   var code : String

   init(code: String) {
     self.code = code
   }
}


class Obj2: NSObject {
   var codeObj : Obj1
   var value : Double

   init(primary: Currency, value: Double) {
     self.primary = primary
     self.value = value
   }
}
```

I have an array of Obj2 and I'm trying to update the array `[Obj2]` in such a way that the array only contains Obj2 whose codeObj.code are equal. Will including the Equatable protocol help in this?

I have tried this:

```
  let filteredArray =  array1.filter( { (c1: Obj2) -> Bool in
                return conversion2.contains(where: { (c2: Obj2) -> Bool in
                    return c1.codeObj.code == c2.codeObj.code;
                })
            }) + array2.filter( { (c2: Obj2) -> Bool in
                return conversion1.contains(where: { (c1: Obj2) -> Bool in
                    return c1.codeObj.code == c2.codeObj.code;
                })
            })
```

IS there a way to simplify this?

Comment: But equal to what? What happens if multiply `Obj` have same code? For example, what is the output if you have multiple `Obj` with this codes `["aaa", "aba", "aaa", "aba", "abc", "xyz", ard"]`? Would the output be `["aaa", "aaa", "aba", "aba"]` ?

Comment: And since `Obj1` is a class, you need to make a distinction between equal and identical.

Comment: `[Obj2] in such a way that the array only contains Obj2 whose codeObj.code are equal` equal to what?

Comment: @mhergon Yes
@DanielT I'm trying to filter the array by just seeing if the `codeObj.code` are equal for [Obj2]
@Alexander [Obj2] would have Obj2 whose `codeObj.code` is equal to `codeObj.code` of other elements. Like a sorted array

Answer (score 0):

The only way for me is adding `equatable` to the objects like this:

```
class Obj1: NSObject {
    var code : String

    init(code: String) {
        self.code = code
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Obj1, rhs: Obj1) -> Bool {
        return lhs.code == rhs.code
    }

}


class Obj2: NSObject {
    var codeObj : Obj1
    var value : Double

    init(obj: Obj1, value: Double) {
        self.codeObj = obj
        self.value = value
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Obj2, rhs: Obj2) -> Bool {
        return lhs.codeObj == rhs.codeObj
    }

}
```

And to filter for equals, use for example:

```
// Test objects
let obj1A = Obj1(code: "aaa")
let obj1B = Obj1(code: "aba")
let obj1C = Obj1(code: "aaa")
let obj1D = Obj1(code: "cca")
let obj1E = Obj1(code: "aba")
let obj1F = Obj1(code: "xca")

let obj2A = Obj2(obj: obj1A, value: 12.0)
let obj2B = Obj2(obj: obj1B, value: 12.0)
let obj2C = Obj2(obj: obj1C, value: 23.0)
let obj2D = Obj2(obj: obj1D, value: 46.0)
let obj2E = Obj2(obj: obj1E, value: 23.0)
let obj2F = Obj2(obj: obj1F, value: 4.0)

var array = [obj2A, obj2B, obj2C, obj2D, obj2E, obj2F]

var onlyEqual = [Obj2]()
for object in array {
    let count = array.filter({ $0 == object }).count
    if count > 1 {
        onlyEqual.append(object)
    }
}
```

Where `onlyEqual` contains:

```
aaa 
aba
aaa 
aba
```